# How can i set unique key values to NSOperation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

In my app I'm trying to implement a `NSOperationQueue` for the web service interaction using `AFNetworking`. I'm adding a `NSOperation` one by one into the queue. I want to cancel a particular operation at any time. For that I want to set some unique key to the operation. So, is there any way possible to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

Create a [`NSOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation) sub class and set one property.

If the app minimum deployment is greater than iOS 8, then you can directly use the [`.name`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1416089-name) property.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
if (![[[queue operations] valueForKey:@"name"] containsObject:@"WS"])
{
    NSBlockOperation *op = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        //your task
    }];
    op.name = @"Unique id";
    [queue addOperation:op];
}
else
{
    NSIndexSet *indexSet = [[queue operations] indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:
                            ^ BOOL(NSBlockOperation *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
                            {
                                if ([obj.name isEqualToString:@"Unique id"])
                                {
                                    return YES;
                                } else
                                {
                                    return NO;
                                }
                                *stop = YES;
                            } ];

    if (indexSet.firstIndex != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSBlockOperation *queryOpration = [[queue operations] objectAtIndex:indexSet.firstIndex];
        [queryOpration cancel];
    }
}
```

If the app is not for iOS 8 or greater, then you can create a subclass of the `NSOperation` and set an identity with the possibility to query with that value:

```
@interface WSOperation: NSOperation
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* operationID;
@end
```

Comment: I don't recommend using `operations` nor `operationCount`, because both are inherently a race condition and those should be avoided. Both are deprecated since iOS 13.